# Delete a row from the add-on

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I've created an add-on that when you click on it, it creates an object.

[image]

But I would like that, once that the object is created, the operator (or the row) doesn't appear anymore, so there is no option to create again the object (this is how it would look once that the object has been created)

[image]

EDIT: This is the code:

```
import bpy

class ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
 bl_label = "Add-On"
 bl_idname = "ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel"
 bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
 bl_region_type = 'UI'
 bl_category = "Add-On"

  def draw(self, context):
    
    layout = self.layout
    scene = context.scene
       
    row = layout.row()
    row.operator("addonname.myop_operator")
            
           
class ADDONNAME_OT_my_op(bpy.types.Operator):
 bl_label = "Add object"
 bl_idname = "addonname.myop_operator"



  def execute(self, context):
   scene = context.scene
    

    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add()
    return {'FINISHED'}
  
 classes = [ ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel, ADDONNAME_OT_my_op]



def register():
  for cls in classes:
    bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    

def unregister():
 for cls in classes:
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool

if __name__ == "__main__":
  register()
```

Comment: Hello! it will be much easier to help you if you provide your code in the question. Cheers

Comment: as @Gorgious says, it's easier to give you specific explanations if we have your code; but in general the pattern for this is 1) create a boolean shared between the panel and the operator that is initialized to `False`.  2) In the operator set it to `True.`  3) In the panel use an if statement to select between displaying a label if the shared variable is `True` or the operator if it is `False`.  You might want logic to reset it if you delete the object but that's a matter for a separate question.

Comment: I added the code in the question. Sorry about that @Gorgius. About the boolean I understand the way that it works but I dont' know how to pass variables (or booleans) between my panel and the operator (create a global variable), If you could edit the code that I provided that would be great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a wide range of ways to do this.  The easiest to understand is probably to create a separate object in the same Python file that maintains the state variable.  I've had to modify spacing on your sample script to get it to work, because it looks like your copy and paste confused Stack Exchange.  Hopefully my copy and paste will work ok:

```py
import bpy

class _state:
    def __init__(self, created):
        self.created = created
    
_object_state = _state(False)

class ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Add-On"
    bl_idname = "ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Add-On"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        row = layout.row()
        if _object_state.created:
            row.label(text="The object has already been created.")
        else:
            row.operator("addonname.myop_operator")
           
class ADDONNAME_OT_my_op(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Add object"
    bl_idname = "addonname.myop_operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add()
        _object_state.created = True
        return {'FINISHED'}
  
classes = [ ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel, ADDONNAME_OT_my_op]

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  register()
```

I added a new class `_state` that contains the shared state and created an instance of that class `_object_state`.  The leading under-bar fits the convention that the class and object are *local* to this file.

I did this rather than other approaches because it is easy to understand and because you may want to extend the state object to handle the case when you delete the object that was created by your operator.

As I described in the comment, I've converted your `draw` routine to use an if statement to select between the label and the operator and I've added a line to your `execute` routine to set the state.

I've left as an exercise, because it really is a separate question, detecting that the object has been deleted and resetting the state; but note that none of the current code has to change in that case.

Comment: the OP code included `del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool` in the unregister function which is incorrectly indented but also apparently not used. you may want to remove it in the event an uninstall or reload adversely affects another addon.

Comment: @Ratt you're right. Nice spot.  I'll edit the answer and remove it now.